# VB6 Check if Excel Workbook is Open

Tags: excel, vb6

I am working on a project in VB6 (No, I cannot migrate to .NET) that involves opening an Excel File and writing to it.

This all works nice and well without much problem, however if the user closes the Excel file, I get the following Error:

> Run-time error '1004'
>
> Method 'Rows' of object '_Global' failed

The code for this error is:

```
Public Sub LogValues()
    Dim rowNum As Integer
    Dim tempNum As Integer
    rowNum = sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    tempNum = sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    'Other stuff
End Sub
```

Obviously, the error comes form the excel workbook being closed and no longer existing in memory.  Finding the solution to this issue is my current problem.

How do I go about checking to see if the workbook is still open, and in the case that it isn't open, open it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the workbook and catch the error if it is closed.

```
sub workOnWb()

    on error goto not_open

    with workbooks("mybook1.xlsx")
        on error goto 0
        'work with it
    end with

    exit sub

    not_open:
        if err.number = 1004 then
            workbooks.open("c:\mybook1.xlsx")
            resume
        else
            debug.print err.number & ": " & err.description
        end if

end sub
```

There is a lot more that you can do but this covers the basics for your generalized inquiry.